# Webpack JSX cannot resolve relative module through ES6 imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm setting up webpack for a large already existing React App.
Seems to be working fine but some modules causes trouble unless I specifically add the extension to the import

```
//not working
import AppRouter from './router';

//working but meh
import AppRouter from './router.jsx';
```

It does not occur in all the relative imports but some for what I see look random.

---

**The error, it occur multiple times for different files**

```
 ERROR in ./src/main/resources/js/cs/index.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './router' in '<ommited_path>/src/main/resources/js/cs'
     @ ./src/main/resources/js/cs/index.js
```

---

**The folder structure for that file**

```
/src
--/main
  --/resources
     --/js/
        --/cs
           index.js
           router.jsx
           store.js
```

---

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const paths = require('./config/paths');

const config = {
    entry: {
        index: path.join(__dirname, paths.custServReactIndex),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, paths.outputScriptsFolder),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: paths.outputScriptsFolder,
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                // Compile main index
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        }),
    ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

---

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "ignore": ["node_modules"],
    "presets": ["env", "stage-0", "react"]
}
```

---

That being said, any idea on why some relative imports are failing and how can I solve so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add resolve extensions. Add the below config in Webpack and restart React app

```
  resolve: {
      modules: [
        path.resolve("./src"),
        path.resolve("./node_modules")
      ],
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  }
```